# Using cursors to summarize per group

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I want to summarize fields per Group with python and need help to get unstuck. I'm trying to get the code below to produce a Dictionary of Groups and their total shape areas, like {'Group1':123456, 'Group2':654321}. The code below will produce a Dictionary with all Groups but with zeros for shape areas for all but the first Group who will get the shape area of only the first row in the feature class fcunion.

```
import arcpy
fcunion=r'D:\Folder\Database.gdb\fcunion'

fidfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fcunion, 'FID*')]
fidfields.extend(['field1', 'SHAPE@AREA','field2'])

#Create list of the groups
groups=[]
scursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcunion, fidfields)
for row in scursor:
    if row[5] not in groups:
        groups.append(row[5])
del row

#Summarize shape area for each group and create a dictionary
out_dict={}
scursor.reset()
for row in scursor:
    for g in groups:
        lst=[]
        if row[5]==g:
            lst.append(row[4])
        out_dict[g] = sum(lst)
del row, scursor

print out_dict
```

Comment: I think this can be done using two lines of code. First use the Summary Statistics tool to group and summarize your data. Then use list comprehension with a SearchCursor on the table that results to write your dictionary.

Comment: Yes you are right. But i want to do more calculations that i didnt post in my question that i Think a cursor will do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work i think, I can't test as I am at home, using the get method, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm, set the initial time you see the record at 0 then add the value to it, it should then add on the new value every time you see it again.

To further clarify, if the record isn't in the dictionary it will return a 0 value, if it already exists then it will get the value that the record contains.

```
import arcpy 

fcunion=r'D:\Arenden_D\2015\08\ELP_Datauttag\Historiska_nyckelbiotopsarealer\historiskanb.gdb\fcunion'                                   

fidfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fcunion, 'FID*')]
fidfields.extend(['skogsmarksandel', 'SHAPE@AREA','Landskap'])

#Create list of the groups
groupDict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcunion, fidfields) as sCursor:
    for row in sCursor:
        value = groupDict.get(row[5],0)
        value += row[4]
        groupDict[row[5]] = value        

print groupDict
```